# Basic react-selectable-fast example not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

I'm trying to [replicate this example](https://react-selectable-fast.now.sh/). It won't work somehow. From components higher in the hierarchy to lower ones, I have three files:

index.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { SelectableGroup } from "react-selectable-fast"
import List from "../components/List"

const items = [
  {
    player: "Dirk Nowitzki",
    year: 1999,
  },
  {
    player: "Magic Johnson",
    year: 1980,
  },
  {
    player: "Michael Jordan",
    year: 1990,
  },
]

const IndexPage = () => (
  <SelectableGroup
    className="main"
    clickClassName="tick"
    // enableDeselect
    // tolerance={this.state.tolerance}
    // globalMouse={this.state.isGlobal}
    // allowClickWithoutSelected={false}
    // duringSelection={this.handleSelecting}
    duringSelection={() => {
      console.log("DURING")
    }}
    // onSelectionClear={this.handleSelectionClear}
    onSelectionFinish={() => {
      console.log("FINISH")
    }}
  >
    <List items={items} />
  </SelectableGroup>
)

export default IndexPage
```

List.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import SelectableComponent from "./Film"

export default class List extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.items)
    return (
      <>
        {this.props.items.map((item, i) => (
          <SelectableComponent key={i} player={item.player} year={item.year} />
        ))}
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Player.js

```
import React from "react"
import { createSelectable } from "react-selectable-fast"

const Player = ({ selectableRef, selected, selecting }) => (
  <div
    ref={selectableRef}
    style={{
      border: "1px solid blue",
      width: "300px",
      height: "300px",
      float: "left",
    }}
    className="tick"
  >
    {console.log(selected)}
    {console.log(selecting)}
  </div>
)

export default createSelectable(Player)
```

It doesn't throw any errors, but the console.log in `Player.js` are always undefined. OnSelectionFinish and DuringSelection work fine, at least the console.log are coming through.

Comment: can you share on code sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

The variable names need to be changed they are `isSelected` and `isSelecting` in your Player.js

A good rule of thumb is to print your whole *props* object when debugging.

Further code can be found on the library's [github](https://github.com/valerybugakov/react-selectable-fast) page.

```
import React from 'react'
import { TSelectableItemProps, createSelectable } from 'react-selectable-fast'

class SomeComponent extends Component<TSelectableItemProps> {
  render() {
    const { selectableRef, isSelected, isSelecting } = this.props

    return <div ref={selectableRef}>...</div>
  }
}

export default createSelectable(SomeComponent)
```